# Is there a way to solve If than statement error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to work on a code but statement First is not executing what am I doing wrong. I want to check if user input if larger than 5 then first will print if less than 5 then else statement will print:

```
inp = input("Whatever:")
if len(inp) >=5 == True :
    print("First")
else:
    print("Second: " + str(len(inp)))
```

Comment: `len(inp) >=5` is enough, no need for `==True`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `== True` in `if len(inp) >=5 == True :` because `len(inp) >= 5` returns the boolean value
or you can replace `if len(inp) >=5 == True :` with `if (len(inp) >=5) == True :`

Comment: While your statement is true, it doesn't answer the OP's question, which is why the IF statement is not `True`.